# Learning how to create a flight simulator

Tags: simulator

If I want to learn how to build a flight simulator, what are best books to start with?

Thanks

Dmitri

Comment: You'll need to read a *lot* of different books in a *lot* of different subject areas: graphics (3D), physics, aeronautics, aerodynamics, aviation, simulation, cartography, etc. Try being a bit more specific.

Comment: I want to understand the "big" components (in enterprise applications "big" components are GUI, middleware and the database) a typical flight simulator consists of and how they interact with each other. I am not interested in details at the moment.

For example, there is an open-source flight simulator FlightGear. I need some basic guide to understand what module of it does what more quickly (compared to just reading the code).

Answer (score 1):

I think your question needs to be much more specific, but a quick Google check yields quite a few books like this one: (using C++)

[http://www.amazon.com/Build-Your-Own-Flight-Sim/dp/1571690220](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1571690220)

Other notes: And If you are interested, in just tinkering around with 3D programming Google some 3D engines like Ogre or OpenGL and try playing around with them a bit. That is where I started.

Comment: I just obtained a secondhand copy of this book. Turns out it's 15 chapters of how to do a software polygon renderer, and only 1 chapter of actual ultra-simplistic flight dynamics that amount to about 200 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Just start to learn some language, if you are good enough you can code a flight simulator with it. There are no modern "How to code a flight simulator in 21 days" or "Flight simulator coding for dummies" books out there.

A good point to start at would be learning basic c++. There are special books on c++ dealing with game developement, just pick one and start learning.

Edit: omg, there are books like that, but they seem to be quite outdated...

Comment: "There are no "How to code a flight simulator in 21 days" or "Flight simulator coding for dummies" books out there."
Actually there are books specifically for programming flight simulators.

Comment: hehe. yeah I was suprised as well

Comment: i added a "modern", the book you linked seems to be very outdated.